Map does not load into the game
I'm currently creating a JRPG-like game in swift, but I have been stuck in implementing a tile map made thanks to spriteKit.
The problem is that the code can't load the map I made.
As I mentioned above, the map does not load into the game. I tried to rename the tiles both in the code and the tileset but I am pretty sure my mistakes lie behind the unproper construction of the project in its entirety.
import SpriteKit
import GameplayKit

class GameScene: SKScene, SKPhysicsContactDelegate {
    var singleWall: SKTileMapNode?
    var singleFloor: SKTileMapNode?
    var houses: SKTileMapNode?
    var heroEntity: Mileina?
    
    // Collision Mask
    let doorCategory: UInt32 = 0x1 << 4
    let heroCategory: UInt32 = 0x1 << 0
    let wallCollisionMask: UInt32 = 0x1 << 1
    let playerCollisionMask: UInt32 = 0x1 << 0
    
    override func didMove(to view: SKView) {
        // Set delegate for collisions
        physicsWorld.contactDelegate = self
        
        // TileMap configuration
        setupTileMaps()
        
        // Set up collisions
        if let wallMap = singleWall {
            setupCollisions(for: wallMap)
        }
        
        // Hero set
        setupHero()
        
        // Camera set
        setupCamera()
    }
    
    func setupTileMaps() {
        // Look up for parent nodes
        if let wallNode = self.childNode(withName: "Wall") {
            singleWall = wallNode.childNode(withName: "SingleWall") as? SKTileMapNode
        }
        
        if let floorNode = self.childNode(withName: "Floor") {
            singleFloor = floorNode.childNode(withName: "SingleFloor") as? SKTileMapNode
        }
        
        if let houseNode = self.childNode(withName: "HousePH") {
            houses = houseNode.childNode(withName: "Tile") as? SKTileMapNode
        }
        
        // Debug
        print("Wall map: \(String(describing: singleWall))")
        print("Floor map: \(String(describing: singleFloor))")
        print("Houses map: \(String(describing: houses))")
    }
    
    // Set collisions based on TileMap
    func setupCollisions(for tileMap: SKTileMapNode) {
        let tileSize = tileMap.tileSize
        let halfWidth = CGFloat(tileMap.numberOfColumns) / 2.0 * tileSize.width
        let halfHeight = CGFloat(tileMap.numberOfRows) / 2.0 * tileSize.height

        for col in 0..<tileMap.numberOfColumns {
            for row in 0..<tileMap.numberOfRows {
                guard let tileDefinition = tileMap.tileDefinition(atColumn: col, row: row) else { continue }
                
                if let isEdgeTile = tileDefinition.userData?["edgeTile"] as? Bool, isEdgeTile {
                    let x = CGFloat(col) * tileSize.width - halfWidth
                    let y = CGFloat(row) * tileSize.height - halfHeight

                    let physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOf: tileSize, center: CGPoint(x: tileSize.width / 2.0, y: tileSize.height / 2.0))
                    physicsBody.isDynamic = false
                    physicsBody.categoryBitMask = wallCollisionMask
                    physicsBody.collisionBitMask = playerCollisionMask

                    let tileNode = SKNode()
                    tileNode.position = CGPoint(x: x, y: y)
                    tileNode.physicsBody = physicsBody
                    
                    addChild(tileNode)
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
    // Sets hero in the scene
    func setupHero() {
        let spawnPosition = CGPoint(x: 100, y: 100) // Cambia con la posizione di spawn desiderata
        heroEntity = Mileina(position: spawnPosition)

        if let heroSprite = heroEntity?.component(ofType: SpriteComponent.self)?.spriteNode {
            addChild(heroSprite)
            configureHeroPhysics(heroSprite)
        }
    }

    // Set hero physically
    func configureHeroPhysics(_ heroSprite: SKSpriteNode) {
        heroSprite.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(circleOfRadius: heroSprite.size.width / 2)
        heroSprite.physicsBody?.isDynamic = true
        heroSprite.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = false
        heroSprite.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = heroCategory
        heroSprite.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = doorCategory | wallCollisionMask
        heroSprite.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = wallCollisionMask
    }

    // Set camera
    func setupCamera() {
        let cameraNode = SKCameraNode()
        self.camera = cameraNode
        addChild(cameraNode)

        if let heroSprite = heroEntity?.component(ofType: SpriteComponent.self)?.spriteNode {
            cameraNode.position = heroSprite.position
        }
    }
    
    // Input key manager
    override func keyDown(with event: NSEvent) {
        guard let heroEntity = heroEntity else { return }

        let direction: String
        switch event.charactersIgnoringModifiers {
        case "w": direction = "Up"
        case "a": direction = "Left"
        case "s": direction = "Down"
        case "d": direction = "Right"
        default: return
        }

        heroEntity.move(direction: direction)
    }

    // Inupt key stops
    override func keyUp(with event: NSEvent) {
        heroEntity?.stopMoving()
    }

    // Updates position in the map
    override func update(_ currentTime: TimeInterval) {
        if let heroSprite = heroEntity?.component(ofType: SpriteComponent.self)?.spriteNode {
            camera?.position = heroSprite.position
        }
    }
}



Are you receiving any errors? If so, please [edit] the question and provide the full error as text inside it. Please keep in mind that StackOverflow is an English-only website, it could be beneficial to translate the comments in the code posted to English for a better response. I've removed most of the bloat in the question and the part where you request off-site resources as this would make your question not focused and off-topic. Please revise and [edit] if you don't agree.

Thank you a lot for your patience, I am new and do not know well how it works. I am fine with the changes you made and say thanks again. I do not get any errors (those in re I mean). What I get is feedback by the debug:
Wall map: nil
Floor map: nil
Houses map: nil.
I have understood that the code does not find the scene along with its tile map but I cannot understand why.

@ミレイナDid you create the scene using Xcode's scene editor? If so, you must load the .sks file into your game by calling the SKScene initializer and supplying the name of the scene file. Newly created SpriteKit projects have a newGameScene function inside the GameScene class file that contains the code to load the scene from the .sks file. If you create a new SpriteKit game project, you can copy that function into your GameScene class file, and your code should be able to find the scene.
